# Members Only site with Feed Keys

Tags: plugins, feed, private, plugin-members

I've had good luck for several years (6 years!) running WordPress with [Members Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/) and [Feed Keys](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-key/). This provided a completely members only blog (no external view at all) as well as private RSS feeds for those members who want it.

It looks like a recent update has caused some piece of functionality to stop working, and new feed key urls now return:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Blog Name</title>
<link>http://example.com</link>
<item>
<title>No Feed Key Found</title>
<link>http://example.com</link>
<description>
You need to use a Feed Key to access feeds on this site. Please login to obtain yours.
</description>
<pubDate>July 31, 2012 14:27:41 UTC</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

So my questions, given these plugins have not been updated in some time:

1. What might be causing this issue? Are there issues with older plugins and newer WordPress that seem likely culprits?
2. Are there now better solutions for members only with feed key blogs? I see [WordPress Access Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-access-control/), and tried it, but it has feed keys on a development roadmap, not in the current release.
3. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authenticator, a plugin on github https://github.com/bueltge/Authenticator uses HTTP Auth by default to get the functionality equivalent to Members Only. It also has the ability to create a token to work the same way Feed Keys work.

Comment: So the authentication occurs with HTTP Auth then, users will put in username and password for their feed then? Is that right? Is this compatible with online feed readers such as Google Reader?

Comment: Is there a mechanism for allowing Feed Key based "authentication"?

Comment: yes, the feed use user/passwort for check to read. Normaly can Google reader this, but many users have problems :( THe idea for an bypass via an key is also active, but not in the source. Maybe we will include this later.

Comment: I'm really hoping for a solution which does not require storing site authentication information in the feedreader. Without some alternate way, like with feedKeys, your solution is not good enough.

Comment: The solution was for other requirements, but you can fork it and create your enhancement, contribute your requirement. I will include later an solution for the key on the feed adress, current I don't have enough time.

Comment: Thanks @bueltge I could just as easily fork Members Only and fix the Feed Keys aspect, but, yes good point!

Comment: The plugin have now an option for a token, please test it and give feedback. https://github.com/bueltge/Authenticator